# Access static member variables using .name and .value in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a class which has the `.name` and `.value` functionality like the `Enum` class but much simpler than `Enum` class. I simply want to access a static member variable using `member_variable.name` and its value using `member_variable.value`
Say my class is:

```
class NameValue(object):
   ...
```

Now if I do the following

```
class MyConf(NameValue)
   a = 5
   b = "tree"
   c = False
```

I want to access string value using `MyConf.a.name` as `"a"` and `MyConf.a.value` as `5`
I am kind of blank on how to write `NameValue` class.

I require this kind of functionality because in `Enum` class if two member variables say `a` and `b` have the same value then `b.name` gives `"a"`

Comment: Take a look at the source : https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/enum.py

Comment: @Mondo-Cane My use case is much simpler than `Enum` class. I am looking for a much simpler implementation.

Comment: @Heisenbug not really, what you want requires all the metaclass machinery that `enum` implements, and it's a pretty straightforward implementation at that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for the pointers. I tried looking up the metaclass machinery in python docs and also in the enum source code as pointed by Mondo-Cane. but being a noob it is really difficult for me to wrap my head around that. A heads up would be really appreciated :)

Comment: @Heisenbug metaclasses are a little tricky to wrap your head around. But at the end of the day, metaclasses are just the classes for class objects. The default metaclass is `type`. When you create a class with a class definition, `class Foo: pass`, you can think of this as syntactic sugar for `Foo = type('Foo', (object,), {})`, using [the three argument constructor for type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). Here is a link to the [nitty-gritty part of the docs in the python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)